# store the url, then once stored, to load a different url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I basically nees a redirect, but the my problem is the first url must be stored otherwise the other page will not display.

how do i get jquery or javascript to store the current (or specified) url, then once stored it must load a different (specified) url?

Comment: What did you mean to store and where to store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply store it in a variable, because when a new URL is loaded, the entire javascript context is new.  You can store the current URL in a cookie, though.

If you're trying to pass the URL from one page to the next, the cookie approach will only work if the two pages are on the same domain.

If you have any kind of server-side component in your stack (e.g. PHP) it seems like a more sensible approach would be to store the URL server-side.

Edited to add: You requested sample code for the cookies.  Reading and writing cookies in Javascript requires a certain amount of boilerplate code; there are [example methods here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) or you can use [a jQuery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Once you have a simple way to write and read your cookies, you can just do (this syntax uses the jquery plugin)

```
//assuming "newURL" hold the new url you want to load
$.cookie("currentURL",window.location.href);
window.location = newURL;
```

Then on the next page you can get the old URL:

```
var oldURL = $.cookie("currentURL");
```

Comment: hi, yes it would be on the same domain. can you supply some sample code?

Comment: would it not be possible to use the $get commant in jquery?
$.get('http//www.loadThisPageButDontShowIt.html', function(data) {
  window.location = "http://google.ca;
  
});

is something like that possible?

Comment: If you did a `get` like that, it would make an Ajax call to download the content of the page into the browser's memory, and then would immediately load the new page, which would clear the browser's memory.  So the "loadThisPageButDontShowIt" content would never be used or accessible at all.  You could, of course, do something with it before you changed the window location, but when you change the window location, whatever you've done will be gone unless it is stored either in a cookie (the only client-side storage that persists from page to page) or on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a client side script like JavaScript/jQuery, you'll need AJAX.  You send off a request to the server with the URL to store and you can get back the URL to redirect to, if desired.  Once the response is received from the server, you redirect to the target URL.

However, note that this can't be done with *just* JavaScript/jQuery.  You need a server-side script as well to handle the request to store the URL.  Something like PHP, Perl, etc.  You may also need a database or at least a flat text file to store the data.

You may want to consider a completely server-side approach.  Use a script on the server to read and store the URL and then route the request to the proper destination.  It will be a faster and more seamless experience for the user and less stuff for you to build and maintain.